# python raising an error exception

Tags: python, error-handling, exception

I am working on an othello game for class and am trying to raise an exception when the player makes a valid move but this exception is making my program crash and im not sure why.  I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\chapp_000\Desktop\Othello\OthelloUI.py", line 46, in <module>
    s.makeMove(move[0],move[-1])
  File "C:\Users\chapp_000\Desktop\Othello\OthelloGL.py", line 73, in makeMove
    raise InvalidMoveError()
OthelloGL.InvalidMoveError
```

Here is my exception class:

```
class InvalidMoveError(Exception):
'''for handling bad moves'''
pass
```

And here is where the exception is being raised:

```
if self.checkCell(r,c) == 0:
        if self.turn ==1:
            self.board[r][c] = 2
            self.turn =2
        else:
            self.board[r][c] = 1
            self.turn =1
elif self.checkCell(r,c) !=0:
        raise InvalidMoveError()
```

EDIT: to answer some comments I am tying to us my exception to stop my program from crashing by saying pass and check cell looks on my board and returns 0 if no piece is their and 1 or 2 if that player has a piece their line 46 of the code is s.makeMove(move[0],move[-1]) where s is a game bored object and move is a list of 2 numbers from the player saying the x and y location they would like to move to

Comment: Could you point out line 46 and 73

Comment: Mention the details of all the functions you're using such as checkCell

Comment: This is the expected behavior when raising an exception. What do you actually want to do?

Comment: line 73 is my raise InvalidMoveError() line and line 46 is where I call the function it's in (not posted because I didn't think the call was a relevant piece of code to the problem and I didn't want to make people read to much code I will edit in more details

Comment: Uncaught exceptions halt programs. Yes, they do.

Comment: I am trying to catch the invalid move error with the invalid move error class I wrote I just added new details to my original post

Comment: Well, then you will need to write a `try:..except:..` around your code which may raise the exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call your method like this if you want to catch the exception and do something with it:

```
try:
    s.makeMove(move[0], move[-1])
except InvalidMoveError:
    print('You made an invalid move')
    # do something else instead
```

Otherwise, exceptions that are not handled will cause your program to terminate. That’s the point.

Comment: Thank you :) I was a bit confused on the concept of when to call try and catch because im writing my program in separate modules and classes